# How to aggregate and search on the same field in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I made the field on which aggregation is to be done as "not_analyzed".  But now the search is not working on the field.
How can I make aggregation working in the field and also searchable?

Answer (score 2):

You simply need to map your field as a [string multi field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-types.html#_multi_fields_2) with an analyzed part (for search) and a non analyzed part (for aggregations). Basically like this:

```
{
    "my_field": {
        "type": "string",
        "fields": {
            "raw": {
                "type": "string",
                "index": "not_analyzed"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Your query would then search on the `my_field` field, and aggregate on the `my_field.raw` sub-field.